# I am getting following error when i am compile build.xml file for generating test reports with Testng+Ant

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ant, testng

I am getting the following error:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity
>   reference

and I am using the following code:

```
<property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build"/>
<property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src"/>
<property name="ng.result" value="test-output"/>
<property name="ws.jars" value="E:\\New folder\\TOOLS & JARS\\New folder\\apache-ant-1.10.5"/>
```

I am getting error when I am trying to set jar file path as shown in the last line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following:

Change    `& to  &amp;`

Comment: Can you please tell me where I should place "&amp" because when I compile my build.xml file then I am getting above error which I ask

Comment: <property name="ws.jars" value="E:\\New folder\\TOOLS &amp JARS\\New folder\\apache-ant-1.10.5"/>

Comment: Mark this answer correct to help others if your issue is resolved. Thanks